# Thompson Router and public IP address

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, router

I have a Thompson ST546 Router and I want to give it a public ip address and give two servers behind it public ip addresses as well.

Now I am having great trouble getting this set in the web interface.

My router IP address is 91.85.232.65 with .66 and .67 will be the two servers. What is the subnet for these ips? Is it 255.255.255.248?

I have assigned my server the public address but if I try to ping it I am getting no response as if the ip is only a local address. My server is windows server 2008, is there a setting to turn ping on/off that I might have missed? I know the server is pingable internally.

Just to make it clear my ISP has assigned me IPs x.65 to x.70 for my use

Comment: have your ISP assigned you these static IPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual configuration would be that your WAN side should still be set to use DHCP unless they gave you a static IP specifically for your side of the link to them. The LAN IP of your router should be set to 91.85.232.65. You are correct, the subnet should be 255.255.255.248.

Your server should have an IP address of 91.85.232.66 or .67, the subnet mask should be 255.255.255.248 and the default gateway should be 91.86.232.65.

Before you test if you can reach your servers, test if your servers can traceroute out past the router. Also, you'll need to configure static DNS IP addresses in the servers.